# google sheets function that iterates for all sheets in an array then sums the result?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a spreadsheet for my finances and am trying to automate a sheet which calculates totals for the years.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xd9ugIcRitUhy9yPCvLnpEJrjxyD6OmrQAxELOHX2iU/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to a view only version of the spreadsheet with not real finance data. The important sheet in question here is Totals for categories 2023.

I have, with my limited Javascript knowledge, managed to build a function which returns an array of sheet names which contain a specific string, shown below.

```
function getAllSheetNames(string_include){
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().map(x => x.getName());
    var sheets_filtered = sheets.filter(name => name.includes(string_include));
return sheets_filtered;
}
```

This is shown in action in cell l4 of Totals for categories 2023.

The formula currently in C2 is:

```
=SUMIFS('Oct2023 monthly totals'!S:S, 'Oct2023 monthly totals'!P:P, A2, 'Oct2023 monthly totals'!Q:Q, B2) + SUMIFS('Sept2023 monthly totals'!S:S, 'Sept2023 monthly totals'!P:P, A2, 'Sept2023 monthly totals'!Q:Q, B2)
```

But what I really want is a function that would do something like this:

```
def sum_across_sheets([SUMIFS(S:S, P:P, absolute_sheet!A2, Q:Q, absolute_sheet!B2)],             sheet_name_array):
    value = 0
    for sheet_name in sheet array:
       value = SUMIFS(S:S, P:P, absolute_sheet!A2, Q:Q, absolute_sheet!B2) + value
return value
```

As you may be able to tell from my formating I am more comfortable in python than java script so have no idea how to do this. Also any range without a cell reference would be coming from the sheet name in the array whereas any with absolute_sheet! would be a set sheet for all arrays (in this case 'Totals for categories 2023').

Ideally I would like to be able to change to expression entered to other sum formula.

Also can either enter the formula that generates the sheet_name array (getAllSheetNames(string_include)) in the function or would be happy to run this separately in an empty column then just enter the column range i.e n:n if empty cells won't have an affect.

sorry for the wall of text but this is my first time asking on here and I wanted to be thorough.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a way to get the pertinent sheet names, the aggregation can be done with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula. Choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=let( 
  stackValues_, lambda(sn,ra,reduce(tocol(æ,2),sn,lambda(rs,s,let(r,indirect(s&"!"&ra),l,max(index(row(r)*iferror(r<>""))),d,filter(r,row(r)<=l),if(counta(iferror(d)),vstack(rs,d),rs))))), 

  sheetNames, tocol('Totals for categories 2023'!N4:N, 1), 
  data, stackValues_(sheetNames, "P8:S"), 
  query( 
    data, 
    "select Col1, Col2, sum(Col4) 
     where Col4 is not null 
     group by Col1, Col2 
     label Col1 'Category', Col2 'Sub Category' ", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

The formula retrieves the values in the range `P8:S` from every sheet named in `'Totals for categories 2023'!N4:N` and stacks the values into an array. The data in the array is then aggregated using `query()`.

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718),
[reduce()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597),
[indirect()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093377),
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197),
[iferror()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093304),
[vstack()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13191461),
[tocol()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258),
and
[query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343).

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers)(- why/how it works, rather than how to use) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Is `æ` a typo??

Comment: Edited the answer. The `æ` is an identifier that is deliberately left undeclared to get an error.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic, thanks