# Excel Repeat Row based on values in a cell separated by commas

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, powerquery

I have been trying to separate the information of an Excel sheet in parts, it looks something like this:

[image: How it looks]

I need it to look like this:

[image: how i need it to be]

I used this VBA script, but it doesn't work since it replicates the first value it finds in the D column (t) for as many objects it finds in the cell (4 in the case of 1st row):

```
Sub SplitPartsRows()
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim arrParts() As String
Dim partNum As Long
'## In my example i use columns A:E, and column D contains the Corresponding Parts ##

Set rng = Range("A1:AA16000") '## Modify as needed ##'

r = 2
Do While r <= rng.Rows.Count
    '## Split the value in column D (4) by commas, store in array ##
    arrParts = Split(rng(r, 4).Value, ",")
    '## If there's more than one item in the array, add new lines ##
    If UBound(arrParts) >= 1 Then '## corrected this logic for base 0 array
        rng(r, 4).Value = arrParts(0)

        '## Iterate over the items in the array ##
        For partNum = 1 To UBound(arrParts)
            '## Insert a new row ##'
            '## increment the row counter variable ##
            r = r + 1
            rng.Rows(r).Insert Shift:=xlDown

            '## Copy the row above ##'
            rng.Rows(r).Value = rng.Rows(r - 1).Value

            '## update the part number in the new row ##'
            rng(r, 4).Value = Trim(arrParts(partNum))

            '## resize our range variable as needed ##
            Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 1, rng.Columns.Count)

        Next

    End If
'## increment the row counter variable ##
r = r + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

The result would be something like this:

[image: How it looks when I run the script]

I don't necessarily need to use VBA Script I accept any possible answer, even if in google appscript

Comment: I think your code works fine. Just change the initial value for as r=1.

Comment: In PowerQuery you can use "Split Columns", use delimiter and then in Advanced go for Split to"row" instead of "column"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring the data into powerquery with data ... from table/range ...

Right click the rightmost column and choose Split Column ... by delimiter...

Choose comma as the delimiter and in advanced options choose rows

[image]

File .. close and load ... back to excel

Comment: It seems I have been doing it complicated just by myself. Thank you so much for the information because it did just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> I accept any possible answer, even if in google appscript

What you are asking can be done with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula. The answers from [Ike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77444671/13045193) and [Mayukh Bhattacharya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77445234/13045193) show how in Microsoft Excel 365. To do the same in Google Sheets, use this pattern:

```
=let( 
  fixed, A1:C, 
  dist, D1:D, 
  null, tocol(æ, 2), 
  reduce(null, dist, lambda(result, d, if(len(d), 
    vstack( 
      result, 
      reduce(null, split(d, ","), lambda(a, v, 
        vstack(a, hstack(index(fixed, row(d)), v)) 
      )) 
    ), 
    result  
  ))) 
)
```

See [How to unpivot data that has multiple column groups in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76199023/13045193)

Comment: I am marking this as favorite, it will come really handful. Thank you.

Comment: So, `null` doesn't add a row. Interesting way to avoid the initial value of the accumulator.

Comment: Yea, we already discussed that [last month](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77377272/13045193).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula instead:

```vb
=LET(d,A1:D3,
DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)),LAMBDA(result1,i,VSTACK(result1,
           DROP(REDUCE("",TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(d,i,4),",")),
                  LAMBDA(result2,x,VSTACK(result2,HSTACK(DROP(CHOOSEROWS(d,i),,-1),x)))),1)))),1))
```

`TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT` splits your column D values into rows - which are then stacked with the according header data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted then one could use the following formula. Using recursive <kbd>REDUCE</kbd> once

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A5</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, A1:D3,
     Ψ, LAMBDA(φ,δ,VSTACK(φ,IF({1,1,1,0},INDEX(α,δ,0),TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(α,δ,4),,",")))),
     DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),Ψ),1))
```

---

Basically the above formula is :

```
=LET(α, A1:D3,
 DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),LAMBDA(φ,δ,VSTACK(φ,IF({1,1,1,0},INDEX(α,δ,0),TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(α,δ,4),,","))))),1))
```

---

And bit longer method, but without using any <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> helper functions:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A5</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, A1:D3,
     φ, TAKE(α,,-1),
     δ, MAX(LEN(φ)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(φ,",",))+1),
     Ψ, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&φ,",",SEQUENCE(,δ)),","),
     ε, HSTACK(INDEX(TAKE(α,,3),INT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)*δ,,,1/δ)),SEQUENCE(,3)),TOCOL(Ψ)),
     FILTER(ε,1-ISERROR(TAKE(ε,,-1))))
```

---

Comment: I like the use of `IF({1,1,1,0},` to avoid mapping it, or referencing to it's own calculation. 
The `Ψ` can be placed inside the Reduce directly. No real difference, but shorter:
`=LET(
     α, A1:D3,
     DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),LAMBDA(φ,δ,VSTACK(φ,IF({1,1,1,0},INDEX(α,δ,0),TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(α,δ,4),,","))))),1))
`

Comment: @P.b Sir I did to break into steps! But Yes you are absolutely correct!

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next VBA solution. It uses arrays and working mostly in memory should be very fast even for huge ranges to be processed. It processes as many rows are in the respective sheet (based on the last cell in A:A column) and how many columns you choose when load `arr`. The processed array content is dropped in a destination sheet. The following code returns in the Next sheet (after the active one), so it should be empty. But you may choose any other sheet to do it:

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrSpl, arrFin, count As Long
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, k As Long
 Const SplCol As Long = 4 'the column number containing the comma separated strings
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
 lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 Set wsDest = ws.Next 'use here the destination sheet you need
 
 arr = ws.Range("A1:K" & lastR).value 'place the range in an array for faster processing
 
 'Determine the number of rows for the Final Array (arrFin)
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    count = count + UBound(Split(arr(i, SplCol), ",")) + 1
 Next i
 
 'Redim the final array according to determined count:
 ReDim arrFin(1 To count, 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'processing the array elements as required:
    arrSpl = Split(arr(i, SplCol), ",")  'split the string from SplCol
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrSpl)          'iterate between each split array elements
        k = k + 1                        'increment the row of arrFin
        For m = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)      'iterate between the array columns:
            If m = SplCol Then           'for SplCol, use the array element
                arrFin(k, m) = arrSpl(j)
            Else
                arrFin(k, m) = arr(i, m) 'for the rest of columns, use the existing values
            End If
        Next m
    Next j
 Next i
 
 'drop the processed final array, at once:
 wsDest.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
 wsDest.Activate
 
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it. If something not clear enough, even if I tried commenting all code lines, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: It is absolutily fantastic, thank you, I tested it and works just perfect.